# How do I call the values of arrays that are stored in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, c++11

So I'm trying to store arrays inside another array and I'm having a hard time trying to print all the values out.

Not sure if this is possible in c++ but this is possible with python and have tried it.

```
#define ROW 7

int one[ROW], two[ROW], three[ROW], four[ROW], five[ROW], six[ROW], seven[ROW]; 
int grid[7];

void initialize() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        one[i] = 0;
        two[i] = 0;
        three[i] = 0;
        four[i] = 0;
        five[i] = 0;
        six[i] = 0;
        seven[i] = 0;
    }
    grid[0] = *one;
    grid[1] = *two;
    grid[2] = *three;
    grid[3] = *four;
    grid[4] = *five;
    grid[5] = *six;
    grid[6] = *seven;
}

void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    int bro = grid[i];
        cout << grid[i] << endl;

        for (int elem : grid[i]) {
            cout << elem << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this error :

```
error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
             for (int elem : grid[i]) {

error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
             for (int elem : grid[i]) {
```

Comment: Rather than having 7 parallel arrays, you may want to have one array of a structure containing 7 ints.

Comment: Another idea is to have a 2D matrix.  With a 2D matrix, you don't need to specify the name of each variable.

Comment: I am backing @molbdnilo's comment. if you're on it provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem please.

Comment: Neither "begin" nor "end" are in the code you posted. Please give more context.

Comment: `grid[i]` is *one* `int`, not an array. And so are `*one`, `*two`, et cetera. Consider investing in a good book; learning by trial and error is time-consuming and breeds superstition.

Comment: `grid` holds 7 `int`s, not 7 `int` pointers. Use `int grid*[7];` and `grid[0] = one;` etc. - or just use `std::vector`/`std::array`.

Comment: See `std::fill` to initialize an array with a single value.

Comment: @Chipster Range-for is defined in terms of `begin` and `end`. OP is trying to call `begin(int)` and `end(int)` which doesn't work for obvious reasons.

Comment: The variable `bro` is not used int the `print` function, so you should remove it.

Comment: So many answers with 2D arrays, just take your pick.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I must still not be understanding something. I'm not seeing begin and end in the code anywhere. So where is the error coming from?

Comment: @Chipster https://godbolt.org/z/QJLxyk - also see the explanation section of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for.

Comment: @Chipster Range based for loops are only syntactic sugar which is based on `std::begin()` and `std::end()`.

Comment: @Chipster Range-for has been in C++ since C++11. But no idea if (or which version of) VS2010 supports it.

Comment: @MaxLanghof thanks. I got you now.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
int grid[7];
```

Declare a one dimentional array strictly.

This:

```
grid[0] = *one;
```

It does not assign the array into the first element. With C-style array, `*arr` is equivalent to `arr[0]`. So you assign the first number inside `one` into `grid[0]`.

Types cannot change in C++. You'll have to declare a 2D array if that's what you want:

```
int grid[7][7];
```

If you want to copy arrays around, raw array won't do the job. Using `std::array` will fix copy:

```
constexpr int row = 7;
std::array<std::array<int, row>, row> grid;
std::array<int, row> one;

// ...

grid[0] = one; // copy one into a row of grid correctly
```

By the way, global variables are zero initialized by default.

Comment: Thankss, I've tried the two-dimensional approach and it worked :)

Comment: @princejoogie Good! Also, try `constexpr int` instead of the macro, and `std::array` if possible.

Comment: what's the difference of constexpr from const?

Comment: `const` is a variable that its value cannot change. `constexpr` is a constant variable that its value is available at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't know this was possible in c++ but apparently it is and it works just fine.

```
int arr[7][7] = {
        {
            0,1,0,0,0,0,0
        },
        {
            0,0,2,0,0,0,0
        },
        {
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        },
        {
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        },
        {
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        },
        {
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        },
        {
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        },
    };


for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " | ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

result:
0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```